# jquery off not unbinding

Tags: javascript, ember.js, jquery

I'm writing a generic control (using ember.js) which needs to catch all clicks. Depending on where the user has clicked, I need to perform custom logic. (e.g. Clicking outside, will hide elements. Clicking on a input will show a dropdown).

Unfortunately I can't unbind the event properly when closing the control. The above logic will still run, event though the unbind/off code has run. (Everything else works fine)

I'm registering the event like this:

```
$('body').on('click.autocomplete' + this.elementId, function (e) {
..
});
```

And deregistering it like this:

```
$('body').off('click.autocomplete' + this.elementId);
```

How can unbind the event properly?

**Update:** 
I was able to pinpoint the issue more precisely . When closing the view, the event was triggered once more BEFORE calling off(), but nonetheless run afterwards.

A workaround fix is the following:

```
$('body').on('click.autocomplete' + this.elementId, function (e) {
   if (!self.elementId)
         return;
});
```

Would be nice to clear that specific event queue upon calling off, though..

Comment: That should absolutely work. See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/xDH4e/ It's contrived, but it shows the process.

Comment: are you using willDestroyElement hook to unbind?

Comment: @CodeJack: Yes, i'm using the willDestroyElement hook

Comment: @ZenMaster:Ok. Thanks for the reasurance. Then it will probably boil down to an ember related issue.

Comment: `$('button').unbind('click')`

Comment: Thanks for the sanity checks. I've updated the question..